# Creating custom Android project templates in Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Every app I make starts out with a number of common base classes, interfaces, utility classes and a basic package structure that has been working for me.  Is there a way for me to set up a project template in Eclipse that will give me all of the basic Android project stuff PLUS a bunch of custom packages, classes and interfaces?

I guess I could just put all of this stuff into one or more libraries as opposed to creating a whole project template, so if you have a preferred approach or information/links/etc on how to do any of the above, please share (I'm relatively inexperienced with Eclipse, so the more detail the better).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider splitting out your common code into a library and managing it with [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/).  That way, you could just have any new projects declare the library as a dependency, and it'll get pulled in and compiled with your project.

Maven does have a slight learning curve, but it might be a good solution if you plan on reusing a lot of code.  Add the [Maven plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/) to Eclipse and it'll play nicely with it too.  If you decide to go that route, here's a good [reference](http://www.sonatype.com/products/maven/documentation/book-defguide).

Comment: Still doesn't answer the question of actually using maven with an Android project.  I found one solution here(http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/), although I haven't used it.